# Convert &#038 to &

Tags: php, wordpress

Ho you all, I've got a script in a Wordpress post that sends the value of 4 variable to a URL.

The fact is that since natively WordPress converts & to &#038, the URL that is meant to recive those variable cannot get them, since the final URL will be

`http://localhost/php/add.php?a=VALUE1&#038;b=VALUE2&#038;c=VALUE3&#038;d=VALUE4`

instead of `http://localhost/php/add.php?a=VALUE1&b=VALUE2&c=VALUE3&d=VALUE4`

Now I know that it is possible to fix this problem by commenting to lines in wp-includes/formatting.php, but I'm looking for a PHP function that can convert the URL with '&#038' to an URL with just '&'.

Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need urlencode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [**`htmlspecialchars_decode()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). Consider this example:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/php/add.php?a=VALUE1&#038;b=VALUE2&#038;c=VALUE3&#038;d=VALUE4';
$url = htmlspecialchars_decode($url);
echo $url;
// http://localhost/php/add.php?a=VALUE1&b=VALUE2&c=VALUE3&d=VALUE4
```